# why doesnt this return "Success" to the client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What I want to do is simply send a message to the client after I have found the query they are looking for. When write head is outside of the function, it works fine. but when it is inside the call back it only returns a blank space (nothing). Why is this? Everything else works inside the callback, why cant I send a simple success message??

HOME.html

It is a simple password and username box which I Post to the backend. I am using xhr.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Little structure
        </title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="demo">
            <a href = "home.html">HOME</a>

            <h1 id = "factor">Click ere</h1>
            <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Submit</button></br>
            <input id = "userName"></input> </br>
            <input id = "userPW" type = "password"></input></br>
        </div>

        <script>
            // First you must post and check to see if account exists

            function loadDoc() {

                    //initiate POST request
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:3000', false);

                    //Send the proper header information along with the request
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
                        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
                            // Request finished. Do processing here
                            document.getElementById("factor").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            console.log(this.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.send("userName=" + userName + "&userPW=" + userPW); 


                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server.js

The problem code is I wrote is on line 52.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var qs = require('querystring');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert').strict;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    client.connect(function(err) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");

        const db = client.db(dbName);

        // Get the documents collection
        const collection = db.collection('doc');

            if(req.method == "GET")
            {
                if(req.url === '/')
                {
                    fs.readFile('home.html', function(err, data) {
                        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                        res.write(data);                            
                        res.end();
                    });
                }
            }

            else if (req.method == 'POST') {
                console.log("inside POST: ", req.method);
                var body = '';

                req.on('data', function (data){
                    body += data;
                })
                req.on('end', () => {
                    var postData = qs.parse(body);

                    //Verify the login post request. If ur data exists
                    if(req.url == "/")
                    { 
                        var fn = function(err, result){
                            console.log(result);
                            console.log(err);

                            res.writeHead(200);
                            res.end("SUCCESS");
                        }

                        collection.findOne(postData, fn);
                    }

                    res.end();
                })
            }
        });
    });

    server.listen(3000);
    console.log("listening on 3000");
```

Comment: did you try without Content-Type?
```res.writeHead(200);
res.end('SUCCESS');```

Maybe it's the content-type. Your client is waiting something else (e.g. Accept: application/json) but you return text/plain, so the client won't accept the text.

Comment: I did. it still wont display.

Comment: You need to show us a ["Minimal, Reprducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This is not enough code to see what the problem is.

Comment: I posted all the code to get it running. it is just an html file and a small backend API. I didnt know how much was needed so i posted exactly what u need to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an async problem. On line 62 you call `res.end()`. The function defined on line 52 is being used as an async callback in line 60.

The callback ends up getting called *after* `res.end()` gets called on line 62. It's likely that you just want to wrap that line in an `else`, like this:

```js
if(req.url == "/")
{ 
    var fn = function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(err);

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("SUCCESS");
    }

    collection.findOne(postData, fn);
}
else{
  res.end();
}
```

That way the `res.end()` will be called only once, either in the callback inside the `if` or inside the `else`.